# GET to microsoft.graph.getMemberGroups returning error with TODO message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When doing a:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<User ID>/microsoft.graph.getMemberGroups
```

It is correctly returning an error as it should be a POST.  However, the error it is returning has "TODO" messages in it. Weird.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "TODO: throw HTTP 405 with collection of allowed methods (Allow response header). Supported targets: 'Metadata,EntitySet,Entity,EntitySingleProperty,NavigationOrContainment,NavigationOrContainmentEntity,NavigationOrContainmentEntitySingleProperty'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "668fbd4b-2dff-4686-aac4-0ff62c108edf",
            "date": "2016-02-10T05:08:05"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

this is not expected behavior, thank you for reporting it.
We'll be replacing this error message with a proper one.